# When was the Yad first used to read the Torah?

Tags: minhag, history, torah-reading, torah-service, holy-objects

When was the tradition of using the yad started? How long has this practice been in use, please?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Note that at least one answerer below thinks you're referring to a teacher's using a pointer when reading the Torah; I assumed you're referring to use during the synagogue Torah reading during the prayer service. Ambiguities like this are why it's better to write a fleshed out, explicit question, including explanation of any obscure terms you use. I also recommend our [tour].

Answer (score 2):

> The earliest reference to its use is in connection with the schools of
>   Bethar before the destruction of that place in the war of Bar Kokba
>   (132-135).

http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/15047-yad

Comment: That link mentions teachers in schools using them, not the person reading in public. Perhaps the OP wasn't clear and you should clarify that with her, but I had assumed she was referring to its use in public Torah reading.

Comment: @user6591 What's the difference between using a Torah pointer when reading the Torah in a beith medrash vs. beith kneseth? Why would you assume the OP didn't want the earliest reference which could/would likely suggest its use in both?

Comment: @Loewian there are different halachos for public reading than private. Actions in one domain do not imply a universal acceptance. As for my assumptions about the intent of the OP, the use of the word 'tradition' leads me to believe we are discussing something public and communal.

Comment: @user6591 Technically, the teaching of the Torah in the beit medrash is unlikely to have been private.

Comment: @Loewian there were public Torah readings that Moshe and Ezra enacted. That is what I meant by public in case you didn't understand me. It doesn't matter if it's done in the back of a basement or in a stadium. Private is any other Torah reading/learning. It doesn't matter if it's done in the back of a basement or in a stadium.

Comment: @user6591 But why would you assume the use of the pointer when reading a Torah is limited to those readings as opposed to whenever you read a Torah?

Comment: @Loewian I wouldn't because I don't know enough about it to make that type of differentiation. However, theoretically, there might be some difference. I have nothing against Y. giving an educated answer such as we find x, and I think it is no different than y. I myself give answers like that here. But we must first address what the actual question is and realize if the answer given is directly addressing the immediate question or if it is a logically associated fact.

Comment: @Loewian also as far my assumptions, the OP's tag was Torah-service. Not Torah.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=Jq_BLoQLq00C&pg=PA154&lpg=PA154&dq=history%20of%20torah%20pointer&source=bl&ots=icijJnHpgp&sig=zEXVdf0XeUy2MSNfOJLzXE5z6uE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjasJXO0KTKAhVFwj4KHbR2BiA4ChDoAQgsMAI#v=onepage&q=history%20of%20torah%20pointer&f=false) (It's a Google book, on p. 154 - in case link has a problem,) the first use of the Torah pointer in Europe was in Northern Italy dating back to the 15th century.

[image: Google book, on p. 154]
[image: References]

Comment: @DannySchoemann I appreciate your edit.